# import facebook sdk Phonegap Android Studio

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I use Phonegap. I have already imported the Facebook SDK in Android Studio by adding
 `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'` 
in build.gradle(Module: andriod) file

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
}
```

But it does not import all classes and gets some errors.

```
Error:(28, 20) error: cannot find symbol class AppEventsLogger
Error:(35, 20) error: cannot find symbol class Request
Error:(36, 28) error: package com.facebook.Request does not exist
Error:(37, 20) error: cannot find symbol class Response
Error:(38, 20) error: cannot find symbol class Session
Error:(39, 20) error: cannot find symbol class SessionState
Error:(40, 20) error: cannot find symbol class UiLifecycleHelper
```

It imports only some classes.

[image]

Comment: did you add the plugin to your `config.xml`. If you are using the SDK with an IDE, you need to add the plugin by hand.

Comment: I didn't. What should I add in config.xml? I've never see in the tutorial. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, I found my mistake. I imported the latest Facebook SDK version 4.x, they removed some classes from 3.x. Now, the phonegap Android FacebookSDK is "3.21.1",
so I should import this in build.gradle(Module: andriod) file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.21.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Exit,
there are three (3) ways to build Cordova/Phonegap apps.

1. CLI - Command Line Interface.
2. SDK - which is done via Android Studio, Visual Studio, Eclipse, etc.
3. Phonegap Build, a cloud-base build tool.

You are using #2. With #2 and #3, you have to define the plugin in `config.xml`

The documentation, under [The config.xml File](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.4.0/config_ref/index.html) has most of the information you need.
Be careful, while the SDK version is the simple - developers often get confused because the CLI version is so similar. (search for SDK in the documentation I just pointed to.)

To be clear, the CLI uses [Plugman](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.4.0/plugin_ref/plugman.html) to install the plugin and add the code to the `config.xml`. However, with the SDK you have to add the elements yourself to the `config.xml`.

One last thing, most tools are semi-automated, but you have to assemble some key pieces. The ONLY pieces of code you shoulding look at is the HTML, CSS, Javascript and the XML for your `config.xml`. If you are looking and editing any other code, something is wrong - you need to read more documention.

Lastly, most developer find it easier to work with the CLI, then SDKs - However, Android studio and Visual Studio are the favorites. If you get any more issues, I recommend [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/phonegap). Sometimes the answers for SDK can be rather long. - Best of Luck.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got my mistake.

Comment: Great, glad to hear that. If my answer was the solution, please mark it as so. If not, please post your answer so other can benefit from it. TIA